# Recursive sub-directory processing in C

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory, dirent.h

Ok, so I am trying to process a list of directories and the files within them.
My program works fine so far, except for the case where there happens to be more than
1 subdirectory within a given directory.I absolutely cannot figure out why this is happening.

Below are the relevant snippets of code I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    int i=0;
    int subcount=0;
    char temp[256];
    struct dirent *directory;
    DIR *pdirectory;
    struct stat fileinfo;

    chdir(path);
    pdirectory=opendir(path);
    if (pdirectory==NULL)
    {
            perror(path);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s\n",path);
    while ((directory=readdir(pdirectory)) != NULL)
    {

         if (!stat(directory->d_name,&fileinfo))
        {

            if(!strcmp(directory->d_name,"."))
            continue;
            if(!strcmp(directory->d_name,".."))
            continue;   

         if (S_ISDIR(fileinfo.st_mode) && (!S_ISREG(fileinfo.st_mode)))
         {
            (char*)directory->d_name;
            strcpy(temp,directory->d_name);
            printf("Dir Name: %s\n",temp);
            subcount=subcount+1;
            printf("Sub Count: %d\n",subcount);


            for (i=0; i < subcount; i++)
            { 
              strcat(path,"/");
              strcat(path,temp);           
              processDir(path); //Recursive Call to Function

            } 
             closedir(pdirectory);
            }
```

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not very descriptive. what exactly happens?

Comment: Ok, so I have a parent folder with 1 subdirectory named Test. Within Test, there are 2 subdirectories named Test 1 and Test2. My program processes all the files within the parent folder, within Test, and within Test2, but seems to skip over Test1 for some reason.

Comment: You'll generally only get answers to questions about things not working if you post a SCCE: a self-contained compilable example.  In this case, extract the directory walking code.

Comment: You're appending several times to `path` inside the last for loop, which makes the path invalid after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration is not shown but it likely looks something like

```
void processDir(char *path);
```

`path` should be not be assumed to have space for additional appended `char`, which unfortunately is what occurs with

```
strcat(path,"/");
strcat(path, temp);
```

Further, if there is another sub-directory, `path` is not restored and the *next* sub-directory name is appended (@doukremt).  Instead, use a workspace `buffer`.  BTW: no need for `temp`.

```
char buffer[1024];
sprintf(buffer, "%s/%s", path, directory->d_name);
processDir(buffer); //Recursive Call to Function
```

Later:
You make want to use `snprintf()` to insure no buffer over-run and take evasive action.
Simplification: `int len = sprintf(buffer, "%s/", path);` before the loop and then simply:

```
strcpy(&buffer[len], directory->d_name);
processDir(buffer); //Recursive Call to Function
```

Again, add prevent/detect buffers over-run code.

---

Optional approach: if C99 or later, use VLA

```
char buffer[strlen(path) + 1 + sizeof(directory->d_name) + 1];
```

or use dynamic memory allocation.

```
size_t size = strlen(path) + 1 + sizeof(directory->d_name) + 1;
char *buffer = malloc(size);  // TDB add NULL check
len = sprintf(buffer, "%s/", path);`
while ((directory=readdir(pdirectory)) != NULL) {
  ...
  strcpy(&buffer[len], directory->d_name);
  processDir(buffer);
  ...
}
free(buffer);
```